# Pregunta teórica en C

Tags: c++, c

Empecé hace poco con C y estoy confundido en lo siguiente

Porque cuando se pone

```
n = (i, j);
```

en C n=j y cuando n = i, j; n=i?

Comment: Porque la segunda expresión es equivalente a `(n=i), j;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esa línea hace uso del operador coma.

Lo que hace el operador coma es concatenar una serie de operaciones, separadas por una coma. El elemento que se encuentra en último lugar es el que se devuelve.

Si en el ejemplo que has puesto llevásemos el ejemplo a operaciones comunes quedaría algo así:

```
i;
n = j;
```

Es facil comprobar cómo funciona el operador coma:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 2;

int c = (a++, a+=6, a*=3, a+b);

printf("%d", c);
```

En este caso obtendremos como resultado 23:

```
a++   -> a=1
a+=6  -> a=7
a*=3  -> a=21
c=a+b -> 21+2 = 23
```